# How to update an entity property if it is used in a relationship?

Tags: java, jpa

Persisting of, updates to and deleting of an entity can be tracked with `@Pre/PostPersist`, `@Pre/PostUpdate` and `@Pre/PostDelete` JPA annotations. I'd like to change an entity property if it has been used in a relationship, i.e. if another entity has used it as a value of a relationship field or added to a relationship collection.

Using `@PrePostLoad` is difficult because it's hard to exclude loads which are unrelated to usage in relationships.

I'd like to use a pura JPA/provider-portable solution, but I'm curious about provider specific solutions as well.

The concrete idea is let the user create and persist entities (e.g. instances of contact information) in a form and then associate them with another entity created in another form (e.g. a document with a sender property). The (already persisted) available entities for associating are displayed in a table. This table should be sortable by a counter for the most frequent or a timestamp for most recent usage of the entities.

I'm using JPA 2.1 (EclipseLink 2.6.4 currently).

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do that. It seems rare that you would have en entity which is not used by another entity, that would require a One-To-One, Many-To-One with which is optional (generally a bad thing). It would be like having a loose address not related to a person.

Comment: I explained the concrete idea.

Comment: Does that mean it is a many-to-may relation ? and do you have bidirectional relationships between entities.

Comment: I'm looking for  a solution for all 3/4 types of relationships both bidirectional and not. My application is supported to support exchangable modules (and provide the forms to create and persist entities via reflection (see https://github.com/document-scanner/reflection-form-builder)).

Comment: If all your relation have bidirectional relationships, you should be able to simply count the number of items in the One-To-Many and Many-To-Many (the other 2 have one usage) collections as part of the @PostLoad operator. This does not scale very well, and unless prevented this would cascade eventually loading everything. Normally, if you want a table of Entities you would sort and paginate, so you do the counting in the database, to prevent loading everything.

Comment: I checked out your code, but I swore never to install Maven again, so I can't compile it. You really should convert it to Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I handled the update in the UI by adding a `Storage` interface which wraps `EntityManager` and allows to register pre and post persistence callback (functional interfaces are a real blessing) like

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Callback {
    void callback(EntityManager e);
```

This suggestion has been proposed by another user, but then deleted apparently.